# How does GMail let users use their own custom email

Tags: email, smtp, gmail, smtpclient, smtp-auth

I was trying to sign up for a new Gmail address and noticed that Gmail has an option in which you can use your custom email address without the need for having a GSuit paid membership.

Upon filling up the details, Gmail sends an OTP/code to the custom email and upon entering the right code the user can log in using that email.

How is it possible for Gmail to just get access to an email address without even the need for entering the password?

Comment: I think you are talking about [Gmailify](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6304825?ctx=gmail&hl=en&authuser=0). I tried it, it seemed to ask my outlook login for permission for GMAIL to login to my account. Also, look like Gmailify is only available for Yahoo, AOL, Outlook, Hotmail, or select non-Gmail accounts. Thus, I assumed if you use a supported provider, GMAIL would just ask for your permission through your e-mailer provider's app or system. When I tried to enter, my personal e-mail that hosted on my own server, Gmailify did not support that.  But I could still import through...

Comment: providing Gmail with my server POP and SMTP information including my login information.

Comment: By using OAuth application authentication. Check it here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a google account. A Google account can be associated with any email id.

If you use a custom email id, you can use all the gsuite features like docs etc from that email id, **but** you cannot access your email via gmail.

To use gmail on a custom domain you have to pay ( change mx servers etc also )

Comment: This is the right answer. Sorry but the bounty has expired.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by using MX records.

Mail Exchange (MX) records are DNS records that are necessary for delivering email to your address.

In simple DNS terms, an MX record is used to tell the world which mail servers accept incoming mail for your domain and where emails sent to your domain should be routed to. If your MX records are not pointed to the correct location, you will not receive email.

MX records consist of two parts: the priority and the domain name. For example:

0 mail.EXAMPLE.com

- The ‘0’ is the priority.
- The lower the number means a higher priority.
- The ‘mail.EXAMPLE.com’ is the mail server to which it connects. This is different - depending on what company is hosting your email.
- Outgoing email servers connect to the MX servers in order of priority.
- If you use more than one MX record and both have the same priority, it picks one at random. (This in effect load balances the connections.)

Your MX records are controlled at the company where your Nameservers are pointed.

Use MX records, provided by the G Suite Setup Wizard, to verify your domain (if you haven’t already verified it) and to set up Gmail as your professional email.

After you've switched to Google's MX records, you can receive your email in your Gmail inbox or through an email client like MS Outlook.

### How it works

- Keep setup instructions open and sign in to your domain host in another window or tab. Your host manages technical settings for your domain.
- You’ll then update the MX record settings to direct your email to your G Suite account. It’s like registering a new address with the post office so that your mail gets delivered.
- If you already use email with your domain (your email address ends with @yourdomain.com), you’ll start receiving messages in Gmail instead of with your old email provider.

Read more here https://support.google.com/a/answer/140034?hl=en